# Исключение между REST сервисами Spring

Tags: java, spring, исключения, rest

Есть фронт, который отправляет разные запросы на промежуточный сервис(далее **loadbalancer**), он перенаправляет запросы на сервис апи(далее **api**).

Тот самый **loadbalancer**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/profile")
public class ProfileController {

@Autowired
private ProfileProcessor profileProcessor;

@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public Long create(@RequestBody ProfileInfo request) {
    LOGGER.info("Called createProfile... ");
    return profileProcessor.create(request);
}



 @Component
 public class ProfileProcessor {

 @LoadBalanced
 @Autowired
 private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Long create(ProfileInfo request) {
    return restTemplate.postForObject(serviceURI + "/profile", request, Long.class);
}
```

**api**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {

@Autowired
private ProfileRepository profileRepository;

@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public Long createProfile(@Valid @RequestBody ProfileEntity request) {
    return profileRepository.createProfile(request);
}
```

далее происходит ошибка, потому как пришел невалидный профайл в реквесте, его перехватывает exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

@Autowired
private Validation validationUtil;

@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> invalidInput(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    response.setErrorCode("400");
    response.setErrorMessage("Invalid inputs.");
    response.setErrors(validationUtil.fromBindingErrors(result));
   return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

получается на loadbalancer возвращается не ожидаемый Long(id), а ResponseEntity с инфой об ошибке, и возникает ошибкa JsonMappingException.

Как мне в такой ситуации перехватить ResponseEntity в loadbalancer'е?

Answer (score 1):

Вот похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093388/spring-resttemplate-exception-handling).

```
@Configuration
public class RestCommunicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestOperations restOperations(ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler){
        RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(mmsErrorHandler);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler(){
        return new ResponseErrorHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                HttpStatus httpStatus = response.getStatusCode();
                return httpStatus.is4xxClientError() || httpStatus.is5xxServerError();
            }

            @Override
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();      
                MyErrorEntity myErrorEntity = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), MyErrorEntity.class);
                /* либо залогировать, либо создать свое исключение и выбросить, а затем обработать на этой строчке -> return restTemplate.postForObject(serviceURI + "/profile", request, Long.class);*/
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы можете повысить качество ответа, если перенесёте комментарий из кода в тело ответа.